# Trouble using CSV file to generate chart

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, highcharts

I am currently having trouble taking in a CSV and generating a chart. The CSV file is as follows:

8/1/2014 13:00,2.52 
8/1/2014 14:00,2.45 
8/1/2014 15:00,1.83 
8/1/2014 16:00,0.88..... and so on

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
},
title: {
    text: 'Flooding'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: []

},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Height'
    }
},
series: []

};
```

^Chart Options

```
$.get('HAWKCSV.csv', function(data) 
{
var lines = data.split('\n'); 

var categories = []; //holds the categories

var series = { 
    name: 'Height',
    data: [] //holds the series values 
}; 


$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) 
{ 
    var items = line.split(','); 

    categories.push(items[0]);
    series.data.push(items[1]);     
});


categories.splice(0,1);  
series.data.splice(0,1); 
categories.splice(143,1); 
series.data.splice(143,1); 

options.xAxis.categories.push(categories);
options.series.push(series);
```

**console.log('x axis: ' + options.xAxis.categories);** shows that categories contains the proper values
**console.log(options.series);** shows that series contains an object with the name Height and an array of the proper values.

```
// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

I'm not sure why the chart isn't being generated. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you initailie chart in the $.get() success callback?  Do you receive any errors in the console (developer tools in the browser)

Comment: check that you're not getting a highcharts error message for sending strings as your data values. You may need to throw a parseFloat() in your CSV parsing code.

Comment: On another note, I would drop the categories and use a datetime axis type if you are sending date/time values